# Parse XML and put the data into spinner

Tags: android, android-xml

I am new to andriod programming can any help on how to parse a xml file and put the data into a spinner please help.

The XML file link is as follows :http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since your xml file is large is better that use sax parser .for using from sax parser you should use DeafaultHandler class and override its methods and in its startElement method you should write thing same following for get values:

```
public void startElement(String arg0, String localName, String arg2,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentElement = true;

if (localName.equals("marker")) {

        String currency = attributes.getValue("currency ");

        String  rat= attributes.getValue("rat");



      //and ...

    }
}

   }
```